# JavaScript: Is there an elegant way to generate the coordinates of adjacent cells in a 2d array

Tags: javascript

let's say I have a grid i.e. 2d array

```
const grid = [
  [0, 0, A, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, B, 0],
  [D, E, 0, C, F],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
```

if some cell in the grid can visit all adjacent cells **4-diredtionally**, for example, `C` is at `[3, 3]` so it can visit `[3, 3 + 1]`, `[3 - 1, 3]`,``` [3 +1, 3]``[3, 3 - 1] ```, so normally I would have to hard code this like

```js
//  hard-coded directions
const dirs = [
    [1, 0],
    [-1, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [0, -1],
  ]

const possibleMoves = []
for (const [dx, dy] of dirs) {
   possibleMoves.push([dx + x, dy +y])
}
```

then if it can move 8-directionally then you have to hard code more directions

```js
 const dirs = [[1, 0], [-1, 0] , [0,1], [0,-1], [1,1], [-1,1], [-1,-1], [1,-1]]
```

Is there a smarter way to generate the `dirs` array for the next moves?

Comment: I think that's just fine. Even if there's a less repetitive way, your current approach is probably the easiest way to understand at a glance, which is what matters most

Comment: @CertainPerformance yea I am just curious if there is a smarter way to do it but it might not be as readable as my original implementation idk

Comment: Why generate it? If you only have a small number of directions (e.g. 2d vertical, 2d horizontal, 4d straight, 4d diagonal, 8d), then hard coding makes sense. You might make up more complex directions as combinations of simpler ones, e.g. 4d is 2d vertical + 2d horizontal, 8d is 4d straight + 4d diagonal, and so on.

Comment: @RobG, unless I'm missing something in what you propose, extending smaller spread direction to make larger ones would result in a lot of duplicate cells being found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes!

First: any time you're doing grid-logic, start by checking what [Amit Patel](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/parts/#square-coordinates) has to say.

Honestly, that link has everything you could ever need.

The short version is: if you know the grid width and cell layout, you can easily calculate coordinate offsets of any cell neighbor for any definition of "neighbor."

That logic can be implemented as a pure function that requires both the grid dimensions and the coordinates of the cell whose neighbors you want (aka the "target" cell):

```js
let myNeighbors = getCellNeighbors(
  { x: 2, y: 2 }, // coords of target cell
  { width: 10, height: 10 } // grid dimensions, in cells
)
```

Or you can create a stateful thing that takes the grid dimensions at creation and calculates the offsets once, to be re-used for all getNeighbors calls:

```js
let myGrid = new Grid(10, 10)
let myNeighbors = myGrid.getNeighbors(2, 5)

let myBiggerGrid = new Grid(25, 25)
let otherNeighbors = myBiggerGrid(2, 5)
```

Comment: Answers should not be links only. While the solution might be in the linked page, reading only this answer all we have here is "*hey! call that magic `getCellNeighbors()` function that I got off my hat and this awesome `Grid.getNeighbors()` method, coming from my magic pocket. You need the sources? Naah all this works with magic™.*"